# Question about assets affecting performance

Tags: flutter, dart, assets

i hope your having a good time. i am currently in the middle of devloping an application that has a lot of images, so naturally we added them to the `/assets` folder. my question is. does having high number of asset images (about 140 images) affect flutter run-time performance. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this part](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/performance#finding-the-flutter-resources) of the Flutter documentation about performance:

> Flutter’s engine runtime and your application’s compiled Dart code are
> both bundled as shared libraries on Android and iOS. The first step of
> loading Flutter is to find those resources in your .apk/.ipa/.app
> (along with other Flutter assets such as images, fonts, and JIT code
> if applicable).
>
> This happens when you construct a FlutterEngine for the first time on
> both Android and iOS APIs.

So it would have some(probably minor) effects on starting up the app but the exact time between a bundle with lower amount of resources and another one with more resources can only be measured by using `DevTools` or plugins like that.